# How to check checkbox after show modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand what is happening in my code. I want to show a modal box when a checkbox is checked.
I show the modal box but the checkbox keep unchecked 
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance!

```
 <td colspan="3"><input class="solo{{idioma.id}}" type="checkbox" id="mantenerhorario" name="mantenerhorario" {% if mantenerhorarioanterior == 1 %} checked {% endif %} 
 data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" > Mantener horario del año anterior</td>

 $("#mantenerhorario").click( function(){
        $('body').append('<div id="modalMantenerHorario" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" 
        aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Aviso</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>my msg.</p></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Aceptar</button></div></div>');
        $('#modalMantenerHorario').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#modalMantenerHorario').modal({show:true});
        $("#mantenerhorario").attr('checked', true);
    });
```

Comment: *"I want to show a modal box when a checkbox is checked and check the checkbox"* - doesn't make sense. You checked it already for showing the model, then why should you check it again?

Comment: My checkbox show modal box, but not keep checked the checkbox. Do you understand?

Comment: @TJ he means that his checkbox doesn't stay checked after popping the modal box

Comment: Thanks Alex, my english skills are not very good

Answer (score 2):

For use with checkboxes you should use the prop function so

```
$("#mantenerhorario").attr('checked', true);
```

must become

```
$("#mantenerhorario").prop('checked', true);
```

As you are using this function in an event of the same object you could do

```
$(this).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks Telmo, I have tested your code before but it doesn't work. It is very weird

Comment: Checked your code. You didn't close the input tag. Maybe that's it. You should also use the prop function with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

I have removed this part of code

> data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"

from here

```
 <input class="solo{{idioma.id}}" type="checkbox" id="mantenerhorario" name="mantenerhorario" 
 {% if mantenerhorarioanterior == 1 %} checked {% endif %} data-target="#myModal" 
 data-toggle="modal" >
```

and it works.

```
 <input class="solo{{idioma.id}}" type="checkbox" id="mantenerhorario" name="mantenerhorario" 
 {% if mantenerhorarioanterior == 1 %} checked {% endif %}>

 $("#mantenerhorario").click( function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="modalMantenerHorario" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Aviso</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>my msg.</p></div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Aceptar</button></div></div>');
    $('#modalMantenerHorario').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#modalMantenerHorario').modal({show:true});

});
```